# iPhone generate X509 certificate from RSA public key

Tags: iphone, certificate, rsa, exchange-server, x509

is there a way in iPhone development to generate a X509 Certificate from my RSA public key (seckeyref)

or has anybody an idea how i can transmit my public key to a java server?

thanks Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean. If you mean with the RSA a whole cert then:

```
SecCertificateRef cert = ...
CFDataRef der = SecCertificateCopyData(cert);

const unsigned char * ptr = CFDataGetBytePtr(der);
int len = CFDataGetLength(der);

// now write len bytes from ptr to a file, put it in a POST request
// to the server, etc.
```

which you can write out in binary (as a DER file) or translate into base64 as a PEM cert. Java will like the DER file/format and accept it in

```
FileInputStream certificateStream = new FileInputStream(aboveDerFileOrPost);
CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
java.security.cert.Certificate[] certs = {};
certs = certificateFactory.generateCertificates(certificateStream).toArray();
certificateStream.close();
```

sort of way. If you mean that you have a raw RSA public key - and you now want to add the X509 stuff to make it into a cert and then sign it - that is quite a bit more work. And AFAIK that requires using openssl (or at least that is how I do it) to create the x509 structures; and then the use of SecTransformExecute() or SecKeyRawSign() to sign in order to not run afoul of the security rules on the key store.

Comment: Thanks! can you tell me also how i can create the SecCertificateRef from my Public Key (SecKeyRef generated with SecKeyGeneratePair)? Or is this a "raw RSA public key"? what is the common way to generate a keypair on iOS and to tranmit the public key to a (java) Server?

Comment: That is indeed a raw pair - which does not yet have the certificate info. Not sure what your use case is - but you may really want to consider if you cannot use openssl for it all. As working around the apple limitations is really rather painful. And if you go down the openssl route - you can simply take 'req.c' from the openssl distribution; strip it down and use it.

Comment: The idea was: the client has the .pem certificate with the server's public key (S+). Generates it's own private (C-) and public (C+) key pair. And transmits the C+ to the server (in a certificate or not). After this key exchange the transmitted data should be encrypted. On Blackberry, Windows phone and Android this works fine.. but it is almost impossible on iPhone

Comment: And you want to use normal SSL/TLS for this ?

Comment: the public key should be transmitted normally. Is there a way to retrieve exponent and modulus from my SecKeyRef?

Comment: Just to confirm - you do not then want to do normal SSL/TLS right. In that case; you can useSecItemCopyMatching to get this. See the  getPublicKeyBits method in Apple's CryptoExercise (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CryptoExercise/Introduction/Intro.html) which does just that. Once you have these (as NSData) you can convert and pass them.

Comment: I don't want to use SSL/TLS. I already found this method. But how can I convert the received data into a "Java Public Key" object on the server?

Comment: Java uses DER; which is in effect what you get as the persistent reference from the key reference on OSX. I doubt that this is a public API - but saving it as NSData  works - best checked with 'openssl rsa -inform DER -in ..' sort of confirmation. If you want to avoid the private API - linking agaist your own version of openssl is allowed - and then you have the i2d/d2i class to get you DER in a more documented way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it next days! I'll let you know if it works!

Comment: now I stored my secKeyRef of the public key with getPublicKeyBits on my file system.. when i try to use your command  'openssl rsa -inform DER -in ..' I get the error message **"enconding routines:LONG_C2I:integer too large for long"**. Also the retrieving of the public key on my java server does not work: **algid parse error, not a sequence**

Comment: And you are sure this is the presistent identifier (i.e. if you look at it is is not a short one - but the normal > 300 bytes data package) ?

Comment: how can I see the identifier? the file that I stored is in binary format (after getPublicKeyBits from apple's CryptoExercise ) ..